# MUI V5 Complex Variants createTheme

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I am trying to create a complex theme that is reusable for specific areas where I use an Autocomplete component Outlined Variant. I don't know really how to go about creating a variant of a variant, especially when it's not as straightforward in the items used such as Button which is baselevel and doesn't use a whole bunch of other components within it.

```
const darkTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiAutocomplete: {
      variants: {
        props: { variant: outlinedBacked },
        style: { 
          '& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
            borderColor: `#18FCFC`,
          },
        },
      },
    },
```

I'm not really sure where I should start. I have two different uses for the AutoComplete with distinct changes to the actual styles of it. But, AutoComplete Outlined Variant is ALREADY a variant, and it uses OutlinedInput, TypeField, and a couple other things inside of it. Another issue I was having is figuring out how to change the background of the dropdown; I tried various props with that color and it just always stays white.